# ModuleNotFoundError while package already installed

Tags: python, python-import

My distribution is WinPython and I use Spyder as an IDLE, my python version is 3.6.5.

Although I have so many modules (from the WinPython download) like pip, pandas, and numpy that work perfectly, I want now to download another package called **Swampy**.

So, I wrote to my IPython console: `!pip install Swampy`
and it worked perfectly but when I wrote `import Swampy` the result was a `ModuleNotFoundError`!

Lastly, I have to mention that all the packages seem to be here `C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Downloads\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 1):

I realized that all this time I was writing the name of the package wrong! Although I installed it as **S**wampy it only works if you write import **s**wampy.

Oh god! I suck...

Anyway, thank you all for your valuable time!

Answer (score 0):

You should installing package via this syntax `<your python interpreter> -m pip install ...`

The thing is, `pip` in your system can be tied to another python interpreter, not the one you're using. You say that your python version is `3.6.1`, but packages are installed in `python-3.6.5` directory, makes it likely to be a mismatch.

Comment: I am sorry I have only one version 3.6.5! the previous was a mistake

Comment: Then it's kinda weird... Still try the `-m pip` thing, but IDK what else can be wrong...

Comment: Can you please give me an example? i cannot understand what you mean by python interpreter

Comment: you use IPython? Then this is your interpreter. Write in any console `ipython -m pip ...`

Comment: I tried python -m pip install Swampy. The result was Requirement already satisfied. But still doesn't fix the error.

Comment: no-no. Use **i**python, if you are executing `import Swampy` in **i**python

Comment: I did that. The module is downloaded but still error.

Answer (score 0):

Move that package to the dist-packages directory which is near to site-packages dir.  This will surely solve the problem.

As your mentioned path:- `C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Downloads\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages`

to

```
C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Downloads\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\dist-packages
```